# Android : After enabling proguard org.apache.http is not working

Tags: android, apache, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

In my application, I just enable the **Proguard**. After enable where ever the **api** calling by using **org.apache.http** is not working.

My **targetSDKversion is 23** , so i add the library for using org.apache.htpp

Without proguard the release APK is working fine. But after enabling realse apk is not working fine.

Issue is the api is not calling fine

In my **proguard_rule.pro**

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

After adding these three line the **release apk** is generated. Before that i got warning like

```
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory extends or implements program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
```

**Gradle file**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    }

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'

            java.exclude '**/mediastream/MediastreamerActivity.java'
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    }
```

Can anyone please help me to use **org.apache.http** in Proguard enabled version

Comment: try -dontwarn org.apache.**

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it helps,

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

as warning can be ignored in proguard so instead of `-dontwarn org.apache.http.**`

For eg,

```
    -keep class org.apache.http.**
    -keep interface org.apache.http.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.**

-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpcore-4.3.5.jar
```

Add

```
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
```

Comment: I try this dontwarn, after adding warning will not be and the relase apk will be genreated , but where ever api calling , there calling is not happening @Madhur

Comment: did you added all 3 lines from example

Comment: added all the three lines in the example , but still the same issue , api is not calling @Madhur

Comment: can you tell me that you are using dependencies as libs/jar or from maven??

Comment: dependencies as libs/jar @Madhur

Comment: updated the code with gradle file , can you please help me @Madhur

Comment: check out the answer the library which you have added as jar try to add them in dependencies by right clicking on it add as library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103597/discussion-between-binil-s-and-madhur).

Comment: after adding all the jar file in lib folder and rebuild the project , am getting Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug' non-zero exit value 2 @Madhur